# Lag when win.blit() background pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface, pygame-clock

I'm having trouble with the framerate in my game. I've set it to 60 but it only goes to ~25fps. This was not an issue before displaying the background (was fine with only `win.fill(WHITE)`). Here is enough of the code to reproduce:

```
import os, pygame
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (50, 50)
pygame.init()

bg = pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpg')

FPS = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

winW = 1227
winH = 700
win = pygame.display.set_mode((winW, winH))
win.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.set_icon(win)


def redraw_window():

    #win.fill(WHITE)
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    win.blit(text_to_screen('FPS: {}'.format(FPS.get_fps()), BLUE), (25, 50))

    pygame.display.update()


def text_to_screen(txt, col):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25, True)
    text = font.render(str(txt), True, col)
    return text


run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    redraw_window()

    FPS.tick(fps)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It is sufficient to create the font once, rather than every time when a text is drawn. Move `font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25, True)` to the begin of the application (somewhere after `pygame.init()` and before the main application loop)

Comment: Definitely helped, don't know why I didn't do that to start with. Displaying the image still cripples the framerate t(get up to 16x more with win.fill).

Comment: Does it change if you do `bg = pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpg').convert()`?

Comment: Did now, works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Is the issue solved? Is the answer acceptable? (check mark to the left of the answer).

Comment: Forgot about it, and stack overflow isn't on my main Email. Makred all the helpfull respenses, wil make sure to remember in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the background Surface has the same format as the display Surface. Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) to create a Surface that has the same pixel format. That should improve the performance, when the background is `blit` to the display, because the formats are compatible and `blit` do not have to do an implicit transformation.

```py
bg = pygame.image.load('images/bg.jpg').convert()
```

---

Furthermore, it is sufficient to create the font once, rather than every time when a text is drawn. Move `font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 25, True)` to the begin of the application (somewhere after `pygame.init()` and before the main application loop)

Comment: Good advice. Here's another one: cache the Surfaces you create with `font.render()`. Rendering text is quite expensive in terms of performance cost.

Comment: @sloth Yes of course. But sadly the text seems to be dynamic (fps), at least in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `screen.blit(pygame.image.load(picture.png))`
Just `image = pygame.image.load(picture.png)` then `screen.blit(image)`

( if you keep loading your pictures continuously it will get lag )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).